# Control Panel shortcut folder in Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, control-panel

I'm running Windows 7 build 7600.  Every time I try to make a shortcut folder for Control Panel it comes up empty.  The path I'm using is:

```
::{26EE0668-A00A-44D7-9371-BEB064C98683}\0
```

Is there an actual folder with shortcuts that I can use?

Answer (score 3):

You can right-drag the "Control Panel" from the start menu onto the desktop and use that shortcut.

Comment: Lol  ty such a simple solution but it works

Answer (score 0):

For a simple shortcut to Control Panel, tsilb's answer is best. Thus +1 to tsilb.

But since you had this complex chain of numbers in your question... I'll give a complex answer...

Try naming your folder something like `nameoffolder.{26EE0668-A00A-44D7-9371-BEB064C98683}` which is I believe the way to do it (instead of inputting into path). I may be wrong. Btw, "{26EE0668-A00A-44D7-9371-BEB064C98683}" is the GUID for the Control Panel in Windows 7 64 bit, so if you don't use 64 bit that's another reason it *might* not work.

If you want to Google it it's also known as "God Mode", of which there are like 50 variants.

Comment: I got the "god mode" to work and i like it very much between the c-Panel and G-Mode i have all i need stacked ty vm

Answer (score 0):

Create a new folder and rename it to the code below:

```
ControlPanel.{ED7BA470-8E54-465E-825C-99712043E01C}
```

Remeber that you can use any name instead of "ControlPanel"